# Sum of alternating series is non-zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $S=1-1/3+1/5-1/7+\cdots$. As each term in the series is decreasing and tends to $0$, it is known that their sum exists and is finite by alternating series test. And by considering $\int_0^11/(1+x^2)dx$, it is known that $S=\pi/4$.

I am wondering is there a fast way to see that $S\neq 0$? In general, is it true that for $T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$, where $a_n>0$ are strictly decreasing and tend to $0$, $T\neq 0$?

Comment: If you want $T$ to be a generalization of $S$, you'll want to either start at $n=0$ or make it $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} a_n$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a sequence converges to a limit, then every subsequence converges, to the same limit. In the case of an infinite convergent sum, this implies that the partial sums with an *even* number of terms will converge to the same value. However, those partial sums are of positive numbers such as $1-1/3$, $1/5-1/7$, $1/9-1/11$ etc. so they make up an increasing sequence of positive numbers, and so the limit must be positive.

The same applies to your general case.

Answer (score 15):

The sum is always $\ge$ each even-numbered partial sum and $\le$ each odd-numbered one.  So $S \ge 1 - 1/3 = 2/3 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for any $k$

$$\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k+1}=\frac2{4k^2-1}\ge\frac1{2k^2}$$

therefore for any $N\ge 1$

$$S_{2N}=\sum_{k=1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}\ge\frac12\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{(2k-1)^2} \ge \frac12 $$

From the given inequality, taking the limit to infinity, we can also deduce that $S\ge \frac{\pi^2}{16}$.

Comment: The question asks for a "fast" way to determine that the series evaluates to something nonzero.  Your answer requires the asker to have memorized the value of a different series (which is, to my knowledge, usually computed using *Fourier analysis*, which is typically taught after calculus and analysis), hence it seems like a lot more work than simply computing the value of the series, as the original asker has done.  As such, I don't think that this actually answers the question asked.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Not exactly, indeed from here $S_{2N}=\sum_{k=1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}\ge\frac12\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{(2k-1)^2}\ge \frac12$ we can also conlude without any knowledge for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(2k-1)^2}$. That was my first intention indeed, after I've added the result by a suggestion but it is not necessary.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Note indeed that the argument I used is the same of the others answer but with an explicit evaluation usng partial summation. Nothing new of course but also nothing worst.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you start from $n=0$. Let $b_n = a_{2n} - a_{2n+1}$. Then the infinite sum of $a_n$ is equal to the infinite sum of $b_n$. But $b_n$ is always positive since $a_n$ is strictly decreasing. So the sum is also greater than zero.